# Show that: $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}. \left|P(x)\right| = e^x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity

Show that: $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}. \left|P(x)\right| = e^x$. where $P(x)$ is a polynomial different from the zero-polynomial.

Obviously, for every $y \in (0, \infty)$ there's $x$ such that $e^x = y$.

Should I just claim that:
$$P(x):=r$$ 
$$e^x = r$$
$$\ln(r) = x$$

Comment: You're looking for one $x$ that works. Of course for any $x_1$ with value $|P(x_1)| > 0$, we can find some $x_2$ with $e^{x_2} = P(x_1)$, but we need $x_2 = x_1$ which is not guaranteed.

Comment: must the polynomial be of finite degree?

Comment: Yes, all polynomials are by definition. Otherwise it's a power series, and the statement is no longer true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^x}{|P(x)|} = \infty$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{e^x}{|P(x)|} = 0$ we find values $p_1 < p_2$ where the value of $\frac{e^x}{|P(x)|}$ is $<1$ and $>1$ resp. The intermediate value theorem will do the rest.